# Mandelbrot Set - Predict which value of c will give bounded results?

Tags: limits, complex-numbers, fractals, boundary-value-problem

I have been looking into the Mandelbrot set a little bit lately, and I have a question.

Given the equation: $$z(n+1) = (zn)^2 + c$$ where $c$ is a complex number of the form $a+bi$ is there an easy way of seeing if that complex number is bounded and apart of the Mandelbrot Set?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.  That is what make the Mandelbrot set interesting.  You can define regions that are clearly in, like the main cardioid, the circles attached to it, the mini-brots elsewhere, etc.  You can define regions which are clearly out, like $|z| \gt 2$. In between is a mess........

Comment: Thanks for the information. Could you elaborate a bit more on the things like the main cardioid, circles attached to it etc., and how that could be useful to see whether or not a complex number is apart of the set?

Comment: You might read [this section in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Basic_properties)  There are whole books on the subject.

Comment: Thanks for that link. In that, it gives a way of seeing if a point is in the Mandelbrot set, however I am confused with the notation of it, could you help explain it?

Comment: There is much more to say about the Mandelbrot set than can fit here.  You can search around and find many pages.

Comment: see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals HTH